# how to do max-by in clojure?

Tags: clojure

If I've got a sequence of records defined by `(defrecord Person [name age])` and I want to get the record of the person with the maximum age, is there an easier way to do this than

```
(reduce #(if (> (:age %1) (:age %2)) %1 %2) people)
```

That's the only way I've figured out to do it so far, but it seems like this has to be a common enough scenario that there must be some built-in library functions that make this easier and/or more generic.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`clojure.core/max-key` is a suitable tool for the job.

```
 (apply max-key :age [{:age 12} {:age 20} {:age 30}]) ;; -> {:age 30}
```

Comment: `max-key` does the same `reduce` thing as shown in question :)

Comment: Yes :) I wonder if it'd have been a good idea to use `compare` rather than `>`? i.e. so `max-key` can work with arbitrary values instead of just numeric ones (as described in the doc).

Answer (score 1):

```
(last (sort-by :age [{:age 12} {:age 20} {:age 30}]))
```

sort-by uses compare

Comment: This unnecessarily adds a factor of log(n) to the time complexity.