# Return value of highest key in Clojure

Tags: clojure, treemap, sortedmap

I'm working with these two groups of key value pairs, which is being returned by another function.  I'd like to write a function that will always find the highest key and return its corresponding value.  In this example, I'd be returning 2 because 499 is the highest key. The data that I am working with is

```
({-99 0, 99 0} {-99 2, 499 2})
```

When I call

```
   (type ({-99 0, 99 0} {-99 2, 499 2}))
```

Within the function that is responsible for returning that data it, I get back

```
 (clojure.lang.PersistentTreeMap clojure.lang.PersistentTreeMap)
```

I hope that helps.  Thanks!

Comment: apparently you mean `(map type pair)`

Comment: How do you want to resolve duplicate max keys?

Answer (score 3):

This function will return the rightmost entry of a Clojure sorted map (the built-in implementation is called `clojure.lang.PersistentTreeMap`) in **logarithmic time**:

```
(defn rightmost
  "Takes a Clojure sorted map sm and returns the entry at the greatest
  key (as determined by sm's comparator)."
  [sm]
  (first (rseq sm)))
```

Example:

```
(rightmost (sorted-map 1 1 2 2 3 3))
;= [3 3]
```

You can then fish out the value using the `val` function.

All the `max-key` / `apply max`-based solutions work in **linear time** instead. Needless to say, it's a huge difference.

If the other function could be convinced to return [data.avl](https://github.com/clojure/data.avl) maps instead, you could access the element at any index in logarithmic time using `nth`:

```
;; works for data.avl sorted maps, not the built-ins
(nth (avl/sorted-map 1 1 2 2 3 3) 2)
;= [3 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(as-> (apply merge pair)
      merged
      (->> merged
           keys
           (apply max)
           merged))
```

Notice that when both maps have a "highest" key, the value of second one is returned.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for `max-key` (See [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708898/how-to-do-max-by-in-clojure) for a good example of its use), which I think has kind of a misleading name -- what it actually does is it takes a function and a collection, and it returns the item in the collection that has the highest result of applying the function to that item. You can use the function `key`, which returns the key of a key-value pair.

(Note that you need to concat your maps together so that you're working with a single collection of key-value pairs.)

```
(apply max-key key (concat {-99 0, 99 0} {-99 2, 499 2}))
;=> [499 2]

(second *1)
;=> 2
```

Comment: I'd note that the right-most value will be chosen when there are duplicate keys. `(apply max-key key (concat {-99 0, 499 0} {-99 2, 499 2})) ;=> [499 2]`

Comment: You're right... this will cause problems if the rightmost key isn't the one with the highest value. Interestingly, `(concat {-99 0, 499 5} {-99 2, 499 2})` on its own returns a list which *does* contain duplicate keys: `([-99 0] [499 5] [-99 2] [499 2])`. However, doing `(apply max-key key ...` over that seems to coerce these keys into `java.util.Map$Entry` key-value pairs and eliminates the duplicates by going with the rightmost one, and you get the incorrect (notice I changed the leftmost one by making its value > 2) answer of `[499 2]`.

Comment: Actually, on further review, `[499 2]` is technically not incorrect -- OP was just looking for a way to return the value for the highest *key*, which is 499. The issue, then, is that there are two values for that key. At any rate, I still think `max-key` is a good solution, assuming that you're working with a single map with no duplicate keys.

Comment: Right, it isn't incorrect. (Which is why I didn't down vote ;-)) I just wanted to note an implementation detail because if there are duplicate max keys, there is more than one answer. Your algorithm  resolves that in a specific way, even if it happens to be a sub-implementation detail!

Comment: I like the way you're thinking! :)

Answer (score -1):

```
(defn val-for-max-key [maps]
  (->> (map (partial apply max-key key) maps)
       (apply max-key key)
       val))
```

EDIT:
misunderstood desired return value

Comment: `(val-for-max-key '({-99 0, 99 5000} {-99 2, 499 2})) ;=> 5000`

Answer (score -2):

`({-99 0, 99 0} {-99 2, 499 2})` is a lookup operation, where `{-99 0, 99 0}` is a dictionary and `{-99 2, 499 2}` is a key.  Since the latter is not a key in the former, the expression will return nil.

When I evaluate `(type ({-99 0, 99 0} {-99 2, 499 2}))`, I get `nil`, because the type of `nil` is also `nil`.

Comment: It's not an operation, it's a list, "returned by another function".