# Return Highest Key value Pair inside of an Array Map in Clojure

Tags: sorting, clojure, array-map

I have a function that is returning the following array map:

```
{{498 3} {-498 3}, {99 2} {-99 2}, {499 2} {-499 2}, {100 1} {-100 1}}
```

And I'd like to return 2, because it has the highest key, 499.
Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return value of highest key in Clojure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146366/return-value-of-highest-key-in-clojure)

Answer (score 2):

Not the most efficient way if your map is large, but it works:

```
(def am {{498 3} {-498 3}, {99 2} {-99 2}, {499 2} {-499 2}, {100 1} {-100 1}})

(->> am (map key) (sort-by first) last vals first) 

=> 2
```

Comment: But why sort the whole list when just one pass through will suffice?

Comment: No reason, it was just my first thought. Perhaps it's slightly more readable than the max-key solution though. If the map is short, sorting gets lost in the noise. If it's large, then of course it's best to do one pass.

Comment: Well, I still think that OP has chosen wrong data structure anyway, the solution when input is just a map is absolutely clear and readable. I cannot understand why one would use such map of maps (or array of maps) where every map is just a pair of values.

Answer (score 1):

```
((comp val first key)
 (apply max-key
        (comp key first key)
        {{498 3} {-498 3}, {99 2} {-99 2}, {499 2} {-499 2}, {100 1} {-100 1}}))
```

This finds the value of the first (by spec the only?) entry in the map with the highest first key.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to represent relations between numbers you don't need map of maps. You probably need one map like this:

```
user> (def foo {498 3, -498 3, 99 2, -99 2, 499 2, -499 2, 100 1, -100 1})
;; => #'user/foo
```

It is way more idiomatic, believe me, so may be you should consider rewriting function that returns map of maps (or vector of maps).

To solve your actual problem, try using [`max-key`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/max-key), for it is efficient function created specially for such cases. Here is how you can use it with a map:

```
user> (second (apply max-key first foo))
;; => 2
```

Comment: I am given a map of maps, not the single map you changed it to.  So this answer does not work.

Comment: This answer is based of recommendation. What does it mean "I am given a map of maps"? Do you mean you get a map of maps from some function that you cannot change? I doubt it, because there is no need for such data structure. Map can contain many pairs 'key -> value', so you can get value 3 with key 498 and value 2 with key 99 or -99 using one single map. Unless you absolutely must use key `{498 3}` to get value `{-498 3}` there is absolutely no point in such organisation of the data. It is not idiomatic. Even if you want to able to get `{-498 3}` by key `{498 3}`, you can write a function that

Comment: ...just negates first element of the map. Please tell me why should you use a map of maps?

Comment: Because it is the return value of another function.

Answer (score 0):

In you question you show a map with maps as keys and as values. But it seems you want to treat the keys and values like elements in a normal sequence, so I guess you actually meant the following:

```
[{498 3} {-498 3} {99 2} {-99 2} {499 2} {-499 2} {100 1} {-100 1}]
```

In that case the this function returns your wished value:

```
(defn val-for-highest-key
  [s]
  (->> s (map #(into [] %)) (map first) (apply max-key first) second))
```

test:

```
(def res [{498 3} {-498 3} {99 2} {-99 2} {499 2} {-499 2} {100 1} {-100 1}])
(val-for-highest-key res)
```

result:

```
=> 2
```

Comment: with the input as a vector a vector, `(second (apply max-key (comp key first) res))` suffices. `flatten` is not called for here (in fact it is rarely appropriate).

Comment: But why sort the whole list when just one pass through will suffice?

Comment: @Mark: You are right. I corrected it. It is not beautiful, but at least now it's O(n) and no longer O(n*log(n)). ;-) Can you give me a hint on how to make the code more concise?

Comment: @Dobi, Well noisesmith has most concise `max-key` based solution so far (mine is based on recommendation, so it is not quite correct), so take a look at [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26185794/3687048). However I found it hard to read.

Comment: Nope; I didn't "actually mean the following"; this won't work for the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(let [fval (comp val first)
      fkey (comp key first)]
  (fval
   (reduce
    (fn [v e] (if (< (fkey v) (fkey e)) e v))
    (keys {{498 3} {-498 3}, {99 2} {-99 2}, {499 2} {-499 2}, {100 1} {-100 1}}))))
```